# Passing dynamic value from HTML to Python Flask

Tags: python, html, flask

I need to pass dynamic values to my python view. My HTML looks like:

```
<a href="{{ url_for('refresh_page',
                                   lang_code=g.current_lang,
                                   feature='a+z+',
                                   cata={{ att.get('url_slug')}})}}"
                    >
```

I need to pass this `{{ att.get('url_slug')}}` to my Flask View:
 `@app.route('/<lang_code>/category/<string:feature>/<string:cat>/<int:pag e>')
def navigate_page(feature, page):`

But its not working. I just started working on views, what I am doing wrong. Please help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `url_for` is already a template function, so no need to escape the parameter:

```
<a href="{{ url_for('refresh_page',
               lang_code=g.current_lang,
               feature='a+z+',
               cata=att.get('url_slug')) }}">
```

Comment: thanks. a lot. But now I am having trouble in rendering the url on based of this:
@app.route('/<lang_code>/category/<string:feature>/<string:cat>')
def navigate_page(feature, cat):
    flash('New entry was successfully posted')
    return render_template('test.html')
             
test.html:   
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>
    Hello!
</p>

</body>
</html>